# WorkflowCore asp.net core throw exception System.NullReferenceException:

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, workflow

I have an exception with `WorkflowCore` at the end of the flow.
Because I'm searching the web and there is not so much information about it.

I get an error at the end of the process

```
fail: WorkflowCore.Services.BackgroundTasks.WorkflowConsumer[0]
      Error executing item b40f0553-1184-4417-8aab-9d60961bd14f - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
      System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
         at WorkflowCore.Services.BackgroundTasks.WorkflowConsumer.ProcessItem(String itemId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at WorkflowCore.Services.BackgroundTasks.WorkflowConsumer.ProcessItem(String itemId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at WorkflowCore.Services.BackgroundTasks.QueueConsumer.ExecuteItem(String itemId, EventWaitHandle waitHandle, Activity activity)
```

It happens every time I run flow (at the end).

I saw that this function throws the exception

```
GetWorkflowInstance
```

Has anyone seen a similar problem and can advise help?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: What is WorkflowCore? Workflow Foundation was never ported to .NET Core as it never caught on and only SharePoint used it at the end. The [Workflow Core package](https://github.com/danielgerlag/workflow-core) is a completely different third party project

Comment: `Do you know WorkFlowCore?` do *you*? The tags you used are unrelated. You're asking people to guess what a third party library does without even linking to it. You're asking people to guess what library you use, what may be the problem with that library without any of *your* code. Perhaps there's a bug in that library, perhaps there's a Github issue for this already. Or perhaps your implementation caused an execution error. At the very least post post a link to the library and the *full* exception text.

Comment: guys, this is the link for the workflowcore https://workflow-core.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using-with-aspnet-core/

Comment: Those are the docs, not the project. I linked to a possible project in my previous comment. Did you check the project site? What does *your* code do? If that library has a bug, you'll have to submit an issue that reproduces the problem.

Comment: The project behind the WorkflowCore NuGet package [has 5 issues related to NullReferenceException](https://github.com/danielgerlag/workflow-core/search?q=nullreferenceexception&type=issues) One of those may be related to your problem. Without *your* code though, we can't help. We can't even reproduce the problem